# how to insert multiple fields into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hi I'm trying to submit a webform and insert the data into mysql. The problem I have is that I have setup the fields to have multiple input boxes. For example instead of just "name" I have "first name", "last name" and my address is divided into many fields to ensure the end user does not miss certain parts of their address.

The problem I have is that I can't submit those multiple fields into mysql. If I wanted to simply submit the "name" field I can, but not first name + last name. To be more clear, I have a column named "name" and I want the "firstname" and "lastname" both to be stored there. Same thing with the address.

Here is my html code

```
<ul>            
    <li id=name">
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
        <span>
            <input id="first" name= "first" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="8" value=""/>
            <label>First</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="last" name= "last" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="14" value=""/>
            <label>Last</label>
        </span> 
    </li>
    <li id="phone">
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Phone </label>
        <span>
            <input id="parea" name="parea" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="parea">(###)</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="pfirst" name="pfirst" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="" type="text" /> -
            <label for="pfirst">###</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="plast" name="plast" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="plast">####</label>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li id="email">
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Email </label>
        <div>
            <input id="email1" name="email1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
    </li>
    <li id="address">
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Address </label>
        <div>
            <input id="street" name="street" class="element text large" value="" type="text">
            <label for="element_4_1">Street Address</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4_2" class="element text large" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_4_2">Address Line 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_4_3" name="element_4_3" class="element text medium" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_4_3">City</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input id="element_4_4" name="element_4_4" class="element text medium" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_4_4">State / Province / Region</label>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <input id="element_4_5" name="element_4_5" class="element text medium" maxlength="15" value="" type="text" />
            <label for="element_4_5">Postal / Zip Code</label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my PHP variables are as such:

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$pod=$_POST['pod'];
$sku=$_PST['sku'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$problem=$_POST['problem'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name=$_POST['first'] ." ". $_POST['last'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$pod=$_POST['pod'];
$sku=$_PST['sku'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$problem=$_POST['problem'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
```

Comment: And do wrap them in mysql_real_escape_string before passing them to your database. Never trust user input. Little Bobby Tables might come visit..

Comment: Good tip @Bing thanks for the amendment, also I personally would keep these data elements separated in my DB for ease of searching etc. it's simpler to concatenate a few parts or search across multiple columns than to break one down (parse) later down the line.

Comment: Trim it too! mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['problem']))

Comment: thanks a lot that helped! I was trying to figure out how to connect them and initially did it as $_POST['first'.'last']; no wonder it didnt work. lol

Comment: how do i use the escape string? is it mysql_real_escape_string = ("$name, $email... etc");?

Comment: See the usage in the documentation, you can either build the whole SQL line and pass it through or pass the individual parameters and get the return from each then append them into a single SQL line, the former is probably going to be clearer and easier: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to redesign your table but for making it work with the existing schema, you need to serialize and de-serialize data. see

http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

So in name column you store something like {firstname:lastname}

```
$name[0] = $firstname;
$name[1] = $lastname;
$ser = serialize($name); \\--->put this in db
```